# java: changing value of integer to new value

Tags: java

Question of my exercise

[image]
It shows error. I am a basic java learner. What is problem in that? Why doesn't it worked?

Comment: Please put the text of the exercise into the question, not a link to an image.

Comment: what is telling you the error msg?

Comment: you will get error for duplicate name for variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the original code had been

```
int count;
count = 1;
```

This does two things.  The first line creates a variable called `count`, of type `int`.  The second line assigns a value to that variable.

Because it's very common to assign a value to a variable as soon as it's created, Java lets you combine these two commands into a single one, like this.

```
int count = 1;
```

This is just a shorthand way of writing the same thing.  So it creates the variable and assigns the value.

But if you now follow it with a line such as

```
int count = 100;
```

then you're trying to create a second variable with the same name as the first.  This is not permitted.  Instead, you only need to assign a new value to the existing variable.  To do that, just write

```
count = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

count has already been declared and initialized. You do not need to do that again (with `int`). To change the value, simply do `count = 100;` under `int count = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable "count" twice, so you should simply write count = 100. This is a very basic question. Maybe you should first read some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn first how to declare and initialize variable. Variable can't be initialize twice in same scope.

```
int count =1;
count=100;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

and

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, create the local variable count and assign the value

```
public class CountData{
    int count = 1;

    public void data()
    {
        this.count = 100;
    }
}
```

The above method you can apply the count value to 100 by this method.The count value 100 will be overided and new count value 100 is setted.